# Mailchimp - constrain image dimensions in outlook

Tags: html, css, image, outlook, mailchimp

Im coding a mailchimp template for a client and I am running into problems with images dimensions

The problem is that images with widths greater then the template width (normally 600px) is shown at original size in outlook. I can trust my users to be able to handle such a weakness.

There is one way that works, and thats if the image dimensions are hard coded into the img-tag, although when changing image in mailchimp, the hard coded attributes are overrun. -So its not all Microsofts fault.

The closest I've come to a solution is found here:
[How to retain image dimensions in Mailchimp templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182584/how-to-retain-image-dimensions-in-mailchimp-templates) - But the OPs own accepted answer is incomplete.

Any smart suggestions? Spent days on this now and is starting to mistrust.

I tried this, was supposed to be foolproof, but when testing it with litmus it broke in Outlook 2010 and below:

```
 <!-- content1 -->
    <table mc:repeatable mc:variant="Section: item with image top and CTA" width="300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="full-table" style="width:300px;">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100%">
                            <img mc:edit="article_image" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/3517b92e77c79cf5a2a6072a3/images/c37645eb-f76b-44e9-88ab-f01b1929dda2.jpg" id="contact-photo" alt="" style="width:100%; max-width:100%;" width="300">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
<!-- end content1 -->
```

Comment: Hey David! Outlook is a horrible and angry beast. Let me upload something that works for me nearly every time for you. That being said though, Outlook TOTALLY IGNORES Image resize attributes in CSS.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried though?

Comment: Thanks scoopzilla, I have tried lots of little things, and they usually comprise of putting extra hard coded widths and inline max-widths everywhere. I have updated my post with my latest try! Looking forward to your code

Comment: Here you go. I was making sure I had a template that would work for you. [Download on GIT](https://github.com/seanrawles/Mailchimp_Template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question might be kinda similar to this one [Mailchimp affects my Outlook-specific conditional comments in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41904716/6574757)

I've had the same problem as you. Unfortunately after many many hours debugging en searching the web, I read the following on a MailChimp post:

> Outlook doesn’t recognize the HTML that constrains images. This means
>   that if you use HTML to resize an image uploaded to a campaign or
>   template, it may display at the original size in Outlook. Be sure to
>   resize your images before you upload them to MailChimp, or use our
>   built-in image editor.

source: [MailChimp Knowledge Base](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/previews-and-tests/my-campaign-looks-bad-in-outlook)

I didn't really believe that this could actually be true so I kept trying to constrain the images. I've put fixed width on the img, td, tr, table.. nothing helped.

Sadly I can't really explain what happens, hopefully the link to the MC article gives you a better view on it.
But my best answer is to set a max-width & width to your img and td anyway. And tell your client to resize the images to the allowed size. Setting a max-width and width will also display the #px when hovering over the editable image in your MailChimp editor. I also found out that when you do upload a bigger size, MailChimp throws a lil' warning.

If it may help in any way; see my code below that I used in my templates to make it fluid.

```
<table mc:repeatable mc:variant="Item with image top and CTA" width="650" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="full-table" style="width:650px;">
<tr>
  <td style="padding:30px 20px 40px 20px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:15px;max-width:610px;">
          <img src="/images/img.jpg" alt="x" style="width:100%; max-width:610px;" width="610" mc:edit="article_image">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion. It seems the only solution is to trust the users. Mailchimp should do something about this. Thanks

Comment: @DavidLamm, it really should something about it, indeed! I couldn't believe it at first..